# What happens when you add linear operators or take one linear operator inside another?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be linear operators on $\mathbb R^2$. $A$ is the projection operator on the x-axis and $B$ is the the counterclockwise rotation by angle $\frac{\pi}{6}$. Find matrices of linear operators $A, B, A+B$ and $A \circ B$ in standard basis (S).

So I said $A(x,y) = (x,0)$

so $A(e_1) = A(1,0) = (1,0)$

and $A(e_2) = A(0,1) = (0,0)$

$=> [A]_S = [(1,0)|(0,0)]$

I wrote it in matrix form but I'm just doing it like this here for simplicity

$B(e_1) = (\cos \frac{\pi}{6}, \sin \frac{\pi}{6})$

$B(e_2) = (-\sin \frac{\pi}{6}, \cos \frac{\pi}{6})$

$[B]_S = [B(e_1)|B(e_2)]$

But now $A+B$ and $A \circ B?$

So for $A \circ B$, can I just take $A(B(e_1)) = A(\cos \frac{\pi}{6}, \sin \frac{\pi}{6}) = (\cos \frac{\pi}{6}, 0), etc.$

The with addition, can I say $(A+B)(e_1) = A(e_1) + B(e_1)$?

You know, then I'd write $[A+B]_S = [(A+B)(e_1) | (A+B)(e_2)]$

and $[A \circ B]_S = [A(B(e_1)) | A(B(e_2))]$

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to make sure I didn't make false assumptions